# How do I clip a variable sized widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a chat app where audio messages can accompany the text. The widget that displays this is a very standard looking chat bubble (think iMessage) with one twist - the bubble becomes a progress bar when the audio is playing. The progress bar is essentially just a gradual change in the background color. You can see the layout in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/0510ce05fa80eadb8234689fbaaab734) (hit run). A screenshot of the mock is here:

[image]

Because the chat bubble is rounded, I need the progress bar to round only at the end. In other words, it should always be rounded on the left as it is flush with the left side of the message but it should be flat on the right until it hits the end of the message. I think `ClipRRect` is the right widget to do this.

However, because the message bubble width is variable, I use a `FractionallySizedBox` as the progress bar. 1/10th the way through the audio, it should be 1/10th the width of the chat bubble. Then I use `Positioned.fill` to wrap the progress bar so that the fraction is taken out of the full message bubble width. `ClipRRect` does not seem to play nicely wrapping `Positioned.fill` I believe it expects the child to have a set size:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderClipRRect#3b019 relayoutBoundary=up13
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

[This is a dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/7c5636ce51be10fc287c4e876bca22d2) to the version with the not-working `ClipRRect`. Is there some other widget I can wrap `Position.fill` in to make it clippable? Or maybe a better way to lay this out?

Comment: Could you please share the image for a better understanding?

Comment: Here swapping `Positioned.fill` with its parent `ClipRRect` will solve the build issue

Comment: Wow that works but makes no sense to me because I would think that would ALWAYS round the `FractionallySizedBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ChatAudioTextBubble("Test message"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatAudioTextBubble extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  ChatAudioTextBubble(this.text);

  @override
  _ChatAudioTextBubbleState createState() => _ChatAudioTextBubbleState();
}

class _ChatAudioTextBubbleState extends State<ChatAudioTextBubble>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 1.0,
      value: 0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() {
        this.setState(() {});
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onTapHandler() {
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          _onTapHandler();
          print(
              "Plays the audio and starts the animation which takes _controller.value from 0-1");
        },
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Color(0xFFE6E6E6)),
          )),
          Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: 40,
                  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.70),
              child: _buildTextChild()),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: FractionallySizedBox(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                heightFactor: 1,
                widthFactor: _controller == null ? 0 : _controller.value,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      topRight: Radius.zero,
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.zero,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  Widget _buildTextChild() {
    final color = Colors.black;
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),
        child: Text(widget.text, style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 18)));
  }
}
```

[image]